# How to read information from deeply nested objects in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have json in this format:

```
[
    {"aaa":"aaa"},
    {"Columns":[
        [{"bbb":"bbbb"}, {"name":"name1"}, {"gender":"gender1"}],
        [{"bbb":"bbbb"}, {"name":"name2"}, {"gender":"gender2"}],
    ]}
]
```

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/file.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Columns.0.name" },
            { "data": "Columns.0.gender" },
        ]
    } );
} );
```

but it gave me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
How should I read `name` and `gender`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
       url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/2p254',
       dataSrc: '1.Columns'
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": '0.name' },
        { "data": '0.gender' }
    ]        
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtqxqb3s/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I got the json wrong in the post. I have updated my post. Could you please have a look. Thanks.